# Solve QUERY for showing TOP 5 selling Products

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a table of `Customer_Invoice` having columns of `item_name` and `Quantity`. I want to show the top 5 Items on the specific item & Item Quantity Sold in Descending order i-e if the number of item A is sold 5 and the number of item B is sold 3 then Item A should be on Top and and item B will be on 2nd number.

```
|  ITEMCODE | QUANTITY |
------------------------
|     kb434 |        1 |
| A4tech123 |        4 |
|   HDD40GB |        4 |
|    Cell12 |        4 |
|    Icd123 |        2 |
| A4tech123 |        6 |
```

In the above diagram I want `A4tech123` on 1st no `HDD40GB` on 2nd No, `Cell12` on third no and so on.

Comment: is the column item_code or item_name?

Comment: I want to add number of item_code ie the number of quantity and and item_code should be added...

Comment: i get it. You wrote 'item_name' in the intro paragraph

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select top 5 Item_code, sum(Quantity)
from customer_invoice
group by Item_code
Order by sum(Quantity) desc
```

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - you need to use group by as i did in my answer query check that out

Answer (score 4):

```
select top 5 item_name , sum(Quantity) as Quantity from Customer_Invoice 
group by item_name 
ORDER BY sum(Quantity) DESC
```

Comment: @MuhammadUsman  - i dont know y first correct answer with group by is not get accepted....answer updated after poting out mistake get accepted

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the postgres as DB then use the below query:

```
select Item_code, Quantity from customer_invoice order by Quantity desc limit 5
```

OR

if you using any other DB use this query:

```
select top 5 Item_code, Quantity from customer_invoice order by Quantity desc
```

i didn't checked the second as i am using Postgres DB, so before using confirm that query

Comment: 'limit' syntax is used for mySQL too, iirc.  but OP is using oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE invoice
    (ITEMCODE varchar(9), QUANTITY int)
;

INSERT INTO invoice
VALUES
    ('kb434', 1),
    ('A4tech123', 4),
    ('HDD40GB', 4),
    ('Cell12', 4),
    ('Icd123', 2),`
    ('A4tech123', 6)
;


SELECT ITEMCODE,
       SUM(QUANTITY) as total_quantity,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by sum(QUANTITY) desc) as rank_n
FROM invoice
GROUP BY ITEMCODE
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/da13e/6

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Customer_Invoice ORDER BY QUANTITY
```